# How to extend dark theme to every activity & fragment in Android?

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles

I'm trying to add dark mode to my android application but I can't apply it to all activities and fragments. I specify that the application is started with the light mode and I would like to make the user change through the switch which mode to use. Thanks everyone in advance.

styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/black</item>

    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:colorButtonNormal">@color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="DarkTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/black</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/black</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/black</item>

    <item name="android:background">@color/black</item>
    <item name="cardBackgroundColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:colorButtonNormal">@color/black</item>
</style>
```

activity_settings.xml

```
<Switch
    android:id="@+id/switch_theme"
    android:layout_width="114dp"
    android:layout_height="46dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.835"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/info_darkMode" />
```

public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
public static final String IS_DARK = "IS_DARK";

@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context baseContext) {
    super.attachBaseContext(baseContext);
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(baseContext);
    boolean isDark = prefs.getBoolean(IS_DARK, false);

    if (isDark)
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
    else
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

    TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.info_darkMode);
    Switch switchBtn = findViewById(R.id.switch_theme);
    final SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    
    if(AppCompatDelegate.getDefaultNightMode() == AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES) {
        switchBtn.setChecked(true);
    }

    switchBtn.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
            if(isChecked) {
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
                prefs.edit().putBoolean(IS_DARK, true).apply();
            }
            else {
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
                prefs.edit().putBoolean(IS_DARK, false).apply();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a different theme for the night mode, you can have a night version of the `styles.xml` file

So the light theme (res\values\styles.xml) will have

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/black</item>

    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:colorButtonNormal">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

And the night version (res\values-night\styles.xml)

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/black</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/black</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/black</item>

    <item name="android:background">@color/black</item>
    <item name="cardBackgroundColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:colorButtonNormal">@color/black</item>
</style>
```

Notice that both have the same style name (`AppTheme`)

And no need for following check in `onCreate` as the system will pickup the suitable theme according to the phone's light/dark mode.

```
if(AppCompatDelegate.getDefaultNightMode() == AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES) {
    setTheme(R.style.DarkTheme);
} else {
    setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
}
```

Also keep in mind that setting the dark/light mode with `AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode` will be lost when you restart your app, so you need to set some boolean in the `SharedPreference`, and pick it up on every launch of your app, then say if it's `true`, use `AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)` for night mode, and if it's false use `AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)` for light mode.

> **UPDATE**

> What if I wanted to allow the user to activate dark mode only in the application regardless of the device theme?

I am assuming that you mean "regardless of the device darkness mode" ... If so then you need to use a boolean and save it in `SharedPreference`, and check it on every launch in your app.

**Here is a demo:**

Here I checked the `SharedPreference` boolean in `attachBaseContext()` to be at the very beginning of the app's launch. Then you can change this button by any logic in your app, I am using a couple of buttons to change it.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String IS_DARK = "IS_DARK";

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context baseContext) {
        super.attachBaseContext(baseContext);
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(baseContext);
        boolean isDark = prefs.getBoolean(IS_DARK, false);

        if (isDark)
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
        else
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btnDark = findViewById(R.id.btn_dark);
        Button btnLight = findViewById(R.id.btn_light);
        final SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        btnDark.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
                prefs.edit().putBoolean(IS_DARK, true).apply();
            }
        });

        btnLight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
                prefs.edit().putBoolean(IS_DARK, false).apply();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer. What if I wanted to allow the user to activate dark mode only in the application regardless of the device theme?

Comment: @FrancescoBottiglia glad that could help .. please check updated answer, UPDATE section

Comment: What if I want to do it with a switch button and not with two different buttons? This option must necessarily be inserted in the MainActivity or in any one to propagate throughout the application?

Comment: Yes that is right the AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode() is propagated through the entity app... I just showed you an example of button but you can do your own

Comment: Thanks it works very well. If I have buttons with black icons, is it possible to change dynamically the color of icon?

Comment: I am afraid that can be coverd by another question so that you may describe it well

Comment: Thank you very much, even though I don't know exactly how to do it

Comment: No worries just comment here.. Let me know If you still need help in your question.

Comment: I still have a problem with dark mode, when it is activated if I try to deactivate it it still remains dark. I have edited the code above if it can be useful.

Comment: There are no issues in your shared code.. Can uou consider adding a reproduable sample on github

Comment: Yes, I have my whole project on github